# HTML5 Front End for an Java EE Back End in NetBeans

Tags: java, html, netbeans, frontend, backend

What if I want to use Java EE for Back End and HTML5+Bootstrap for Front. In NeatBeans there are different type of projects: for Java EE - java web application, for html5 - HTML5/Javascript application. the question is how to explain to my servlets to use html5 pages from the other project for the client as a response instead of *jsp? Or it doesn't work this way at all? if so, than how it works?

Answer (score 1):

I think easy solution would be to use "Java EE - java web application" project type (or any java ee project type) which allows all the features from HTML5 project and the java web application is already configured to use frontend sources in correct location. There is no (technical) need to have 2 separate projects

Another possible solution could be to have again the java ee project and have static frontend sources (html, css, js...) in some folder called e.g. app in the java ee project. If you then create either package.json or bower.json in the app folder, you can use File->Open Project and open the app folder as if it was HTML5 project (NetBeans recognize folders with bower.json or package.json as HTML5 projects). This way you could have 2 separate projects in NetBeans - one will be part of another.

The exact configuration of how jsp/html files are being served depends on you framework/server